# PHP STDIN doesnt get the content from piped apache log

Tags: php, apache

I am piping apache log to php file in order to insert **later** the log to the database.

in the virtual host I have the line:
`ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/php /opt/waffy/log2db.php"`

in php I have:

```
$stdin = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r');
ob_implicit_flush (true); // Use unbuffered output
$data = "";
while ($line = fgets ($stdin))
{
   $data .=  $line;
}
file_put_contents("/opt/waffy/log.log",$data);
```

The php is invoked but the file `/opt/waffy/log.log` is empty.

**UPDATE1**

I think i have a little progress when I did 
`chmod +X log2db.php` nothing hapend, but when I replaced `X` with `x` I stopped getting the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

but the file `/opt/waffy/log.log` is not created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script doesn't match what is expected for an Apache piped log script so what exactly is output is likely undefined. A minimal PHP example is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$stdin = fopen ('php://stdin', 'r');
ob_implicit_flush (true); // Use unbuffered output
while ($line = fgets ($stdin))
{
   print $line;
}
```

With the following enty in apache

```
ErrorLog "|/var/www/log.php >>/var/www/log.log"
```

Don't forget to give log.php the right permissions

```
chmod +x log.php
```

Apache needs the permission to write to the directory /var/www/ in my example.

See http://www.sudleyplace.com/pipederrorlogs.html for more details. First get it working so it simply outputs everything it receives and then modify the data and add features.

**Important**

You have to start apache via

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

and **not** via

```
service apache2 start
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Putting this ` ErrorLog "|/opt/waffy/log2db.php >> /opt/waffy/out.log"
` in my virtual host, causing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when accessing the page, even though `configtest` went ok.... Thanks. I think its every time the `>> ` is in my virtual host...

Comment: @SexyMF I tested it it works fine for me. You changed you script and added the line #!/usr/bin/php and looked at the right permissions

Comment: Yes, all dont, except my php is in #!/usr/bin/php5 (ubuntu)

Comment: @SexyMF In your question you had /usr/bin/php so when you just to /opt/waffy/log2db.php it doesn't gives you an error. Perhaps remove the space between >> and /var. so thats then `>>/opt/waffy/out.log' . And apache has the permissions to write to /opt/waffy/out.log

Comment: I am for sure if you following my example and create chmod 777 for the directory /opt/waffy/ it 100% will work. Apache just has not the right permission to write into the directory. I tested it on different server centos and debian. And my example always works, with the right permissions.

Comment: exactly, I got nothing )-:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105336/discussion-between-kordi-and-sexymf).